# Java graphics background moving by itself

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paintcomponent

I'm trying to make a very basic animation where words from an ArrayList move across the screen. To do this I used the drawString() method and a timer to change the x position every set amount of ms. My paintComponent method is currently set up to paint two different words, the word "Hello" first and then the word "World" 2.5 seconds later.

My problem is that the graphics coordinate system appears to be moving, and, as a result, the words I spawn in after the first "Hello" behave differently. The word "World" is set to a constant x = 0, yet it spawns in the middle of the screen and also moves along with the word "Hello". Also, the pink background itself is moving at what seems to be a different speed than words!

What stumps me the most is that if I get rid of lines 32-38 (the code that spawns the words), and only set the background color, the background still moves. However, if I get rid of line 80(the method that changes x), the background stops moving. This means that there is definitely a relationship between my x value and the background, but I just cannot figure out what it is.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Word extends JPanel{
    private ArrayList<String> phrase;
    int x;
    private int y;
    private int interval;
    private Word(ArrayList<String> Phrase,int height,int Interval){
        interval = Interval;
        y = height;
        phrase = Phrase;
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 30));
        for (int num = 0; num < phrase.size(); num++){
            if(num == 2){
                g.drawString(phrase.get(num), 0, 100*(num+1));
            }else{
                g.drawString(phrase.get(num), x, 100*(num + 1));
            }
        }
    }

    public void changeX(){
        x += 1;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getPhrase(){
        return phrase;
    }

    public int getX(){
        return x;
    }

    public int getY(){
        return y;
    }

    public int getInterval(){
        return interval;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        final ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        words.add("Hello");
//      words.add("World");
        final Word test = new Word(words, 100, 50);
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        frame.add(test);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        Timer testTimer = new Timer();
        TimerTask testTask = new TimerTask(){
            int counter = 0;
            boolean spawned = false;
            public void run(){
                test.changeX();
                frame.repaint();
                System.out.println(counter);
                if(counter>50 && !spawned){
                    words.add("World");
                    spawned = true;
                }
                counter++;
            }
        };
        testTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(testTask, 0, test.getInterval());
    }
}
```

I expected the "World" word to spawn at the very left side of the frame and stay still.

Comment: Swing is NOT thread safe and you should never update the UI (or something the UI is relying on) from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is that the graphics coordinate system appears to be moving, and, as a result, the words I spawn in after the first "Hello" behave differently. The word "World" is set to a constant x = 0, yet it spawns in the middle of the screen and also moves along with the word "Hello".

Okay, an immediate number of issues:

1. You override `getX` (and `getY`) which changes the values that the component is using to determine its location on the screen, this is why the background is moving.
2. Your `for-loop` will never reach `2`, it will always be `0` or `1`
3. You should never change the state of the component from within any paint method. Painting should only ever paint the current state.  Doing so could cause additional paint cycles, which could consume all the CPU cycles

Swing is also NOT thread safe, meaning you should never update the UI (or something the UI relies on) from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread (also, neither is `ArrayList`)

See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more details and [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for a possible solution.

In the following example, I've tried to encapsulate the responsibility for each element into it's own class, so the location and animation delta of the text is marinated in it's own class, this allows you to apply different actions to each piece of text without the need of a lot of additional logic.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                WordPane wordPane = new WordPane();
                wordPane.add(new Entity("Hello", new Point(0, 100), new Point(1, 0)));
                final JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                frame.add(wordPane);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                Timer timer = new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {
                    int counter = 0;
                    boolean spawned = false;

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        if (counter > 50 && !spawned) {
                            wordPane.add(new Entity("World", new Point(0, 200), new Point(0, 0)));
                            spawned = true;
                        }
                        counter++;
                        wordPane.tick();
                        wordPane.repaint();
                    }
                });
                timer.start();;
            }
        });
    }

    public class Entity {

        private String text;
        private Point point;
        private Point delta;

        public Entity(String text, Point point, Point delta) {
            this.text = text;
            this.point = point;
            this.delta = delta;
        }

        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }

        public Point getPoint() {
            return point;
        }

        public void tick() {
            point.x += delta.x;
            point.y += delta.y;
        }

    }

    public class WordPane extends JPanel {

        private ArrayList<Entity> phrase = new ArrayList<>(25);
        private int interval;

        private WordPane() {
            this.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
            setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 30));
        }

        public void tick() {
            for (Entity entity : phrase) {
                entity.tick();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(800, 600);
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
            for (Entity entity : phrase) {
                int x = entity.getPoint().x;
                int y = entity.getPoint().y + fm.getAscent();
                g.drawString(entity.text, x, y);
            }
        }

        public ArrayList<Entity> getPhrase() {
            return phrase;
        }

        public void add(Entity entity) {
            phrase.add(entity);
        }
    }
}
```